# How to recover Windows from recovery files moved to different storage

Tags: windows-8.1, system-recovery

I have *HP Stream x360 - 11-p010nt*,
which came with a preinstalled *Windows 8.1* in a total of *32GB SSD*.
The size of the SSD **cannot** be increased,
and the system does **not** leave me enough work space.
In the SSD, the recovery partition was about *7.4GB*,
and I cloned it to a USB drive by using EaseUS Partition Master.
Then, I have erased all the partitions of the internal SSD drive,
and it is now completely blank.

**Question**. I want to learn how can I reinstall Windows files in the recovery,
which I moved to the USB drive?
I have to mention that I can boot with a Live Windows and do anything I want.

Thank you.
bkarpuz

Comment: Windows has (had) a built in tool to create recovery media from your recovery partition. Nowadays you can simply download the recovery media from the Microsoft site.

Comment: I have found a file "install.wim" and applied to the SSD. It seems to work.